# How can I disable Vim "jump to last position" feature in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: vim, 17.04

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 and saw that Vim now jump to last position where cursor was when you reopen the same file.
Previously, this feature was an "opt-in" feature in `/etc/vim/vimrc` with an auto-cmd.
With 17.04, it's enabled by default but the block in `/etc/vim/vimrc` is still commented, so how can I disable this feature properly?

```
" Uncomment the following to have Vim jump to the last position when
" reopening a file
"if has("autocmd")
"  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
"endif
```

Comment: Something is defining an autocommand. Vim does not do that by itself. Read your configuration files and find out where is the autocommand defined. `:verbose autocmd` may be of help.

Comment: I grepped all configuration files (/etc/vim/vimrc & /etc/vim/vimrc.tiny & ~/.vimrc) and no autocmd is enabled. I also browse the whole `:verbose autocmd`and did not find apropriate parameter... Thanks anyway. I don't know if this behavior is part of Ubuntu (or Debian) customization to Vim package or if it's a new behavior of Vim 8.

Answer (score 2):

Just found the solution thanks to irc://chat.freenode.net/#vim.

It's in fact an autocmd defined at `/usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim` that I did not clearly show at `:verbose autocmd` because it's a bit obscur in the way it's doing it. You can simply comment this block to disable this feature:

```
" When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
" Don't do it when the position is invalid or when inside an event handler
" (happens when dropping a file on gvim).
"autocmd BufReadPost *
"  \ if line("'\"") >= 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
"  \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
"  \ endif
```

There is also a buch of new option enabled by default that you can find here.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I am running Ubuntu 17.10, and I managed to override the behavior in my `~/.vimrc` file like this:

```
:augroup vimStartup | au! | augroup END
```